# Form php recebe valor diferente do digitado

Tags: php, html5

Tenho um formulário em PHP. Quando dou submit nele deveria pegar os valores vindo por $_POST. Mas acontece que os dados retornados vem apenas o valor 1.

Não sei o que está acontecendo. Tudo parece normal. :/

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="cadastrar_studante">
    <div class="row mt20">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="name-student-form">Nome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name-student-form" id="name-student-form">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="email-student-form">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email-student-form" id="email-student-form">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Cadastrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Aqui está o PHP. Pego os dados por $_POST. Estou usando o PHP PDO.

```
if( in_array("cadastrar_studante", $_POST) ) {
    $name_student = isset( $_POST['name-student-form'] );
    $email_student = isset( $_POST['email-student-form'] );

    //echo $name_student . " <--> " . $email_student;

    $students->set_name_student( $name_student );
    $students->set_email_student( $email_student );

    /** Inserir aluno */
    if( $students->insert() ) {
        $echo = <<<MSG
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)) {
        $("#modal-feedback").find(".modal-body").html("Aluno cadastrado com sucesso.");
        $("#modal-feedback").modal("show");
    }
</script>
        MSG;
        echo $echo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Outro detalhe, pode ser as tags inputs sem o fechamento.

Comment: Tags `<input>` não precisam fechar.

Comment: Poderia mostrar o código PHP? Não parece ser um problema no HTML.

Comment: Problema com a `<form>` que não fechou não é: testei em três navegadores e todos retornaram corretamente os dados. Enquanto testava pensei em uma possibilidade: há algum script interferindo?

Comment: Não gustavo, ele está fechado, só esqueci de colocar aqui. :/ Tipo assim, eu to fazendo o CRUD na mesma página. Então estou pegando pela action do form para fazer tal alteração no banco.

Comment: Agora que você postou o código PHP encontramos o erro, um pouco tarde demais para mim, mas o problema foi resolvido. O teste se fechava ou não era mais pelo Rafael e flpms, e porque nunca fecho tags que não precisam ser fechadas.

Comment: Mas obrigado Gustavo. Foi de grande ajuda. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amigo, o erro tá aqui.

```
$name_student = isset( $_POST['name-student-form'] );
$email_student = isset( $_POST['email-student-form'] );
```

A função `isset()` só retorna se a variável está setada ou não, então ela sempre retorna 1, que é `true`.

O certo é

```
$name_student = $_POST['name-student-form'];
$email_student = $_POST['email-student-form'];
```

Comment: Muito obrigado CCastro. Realmente, ela estava retornando o true como você falou. Gracias :)

Comment: basta positivar ai ;)

Answer (score 5):

Você pode fazer assim!

```
$name_student  = isset($_POST['name-student-form'])? $_POST['name-student-form'] :'';  
$email_student = isset($_POST['email-student-form'])?$_POST['email-student-form']:'';
```

Ou seja se o índice não  existir então a variável receberá  um valor default que pode ser vazio ou nulo.
Recomendo que faça um validação antes de inserir no banco.